# ResizeObserver does not work in Edge & Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I want to use [this script](https://codepen.io/pbakaus/pen/gOYrwNp) to only show three lines of text and insert a "Read more" button:

```
const ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    entry.target.classList[entry.target.scrollHeight > entry.contentRect.height ? 'add' : 'remove']('truncated');
  }
});

ps.forEach(p => {
  observer.observe(p);
});
```

[image]

Unfortunately, due to the use of ResizeObserver the class `truncated` is not inserted in browsers like Edge and Firefox on Android and so the button does not show up. My question to the JavaScript Pros: Any ideas how to get this working in Edge and Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

I try to test the above sample code with **MS Edge for Android 44.11.4.4121** and look like it is working fine and it is showing the button and functions properly.

Output in Edge for Android and Firefox for Android:

[image]

I also check the documentation and found that **ResizeObserver** is not supported in Firefox for Android. So this is the reason that it is not working with Firefox for Android browser.

[image]

References:

(1) [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

(2) [Resize Observer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver)